# Scripts in /scripts cannot see files in /src/<package name>

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am receiving the following error when trying to run a script in my /catkin_ws/src//scripts directory.

```
robond@udacity:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun sensor_stick capture_features_new.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robond/catkin_ws/src/sensor_stick/scripts/capture_features_new.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sensor_stick.pcl_helper import *
ImportError: No module named pcl_helper
```

All of the files that I am importing from are present in catkin_ws/src//src/. Yet, somehow they are invisible to my script...

I have run catkin_make, and sourced devel/setup.bash. A complete noob to ROS, I warn you.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267671/scripts-in-/scripts-cannot-see-files-in-/src/%3Cpackage-name%3E/) by [jchernus](https://answers.ros.org/users/31380/jchernus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jchernus](https://answers.ros.org/users/31380/jchernus/) on 2017-07-30**:
So after many hours of trying to fix the problem I gave up, copied the package &renamed it. Fiddled around, but it always failed to make, so I deleted it. Tried to make the original again, success, and now the script runs! But why...? Did it just need a clean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason it cannot find your module is that it is not in your $PYTHONPATH. The standard way of solving this would be to write a `setup.py` in your package and invoke `catkin_python_setup()` in `CMakeLists.txt` as described in the last portion of this article: http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile

---

Originally posted by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) with karma: 161 on 2017-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0